# In wireshark, why is the total length of IP packets showing 1 byte less than frames captured on wire?

Tags: ssl, ip, wireshark, tcp

I am doing data transfer of 30 bytes using ssl. I see frames captured as 100 bytes on wire but IP data length shows 99 byte. Where did this 1 byte go? Frame encapsulation is raw IP.
I am a newbie in this field. [Please find the wireshark snapshot in the picture link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64OkG.png)

Comment: Can someone please answer. It might be something very simple I am missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Many problems: first it is not a programming question, so you are offtopic here. You should probably post it **instead** on [sf] or [su] but read their tour and help first. Then begging for a reply does not advance your cause, don't you think that other people posting questions want reply too? And your question exist only since 9 hours so very new. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest for guidance. As for the question itself you could edit it to format it better, put data as text and not as an image,.

Comment: Your dump shows a raw IP encapsulation so you are in some kind of tunnel. You are not giving any specific information on your network setup, nor how you capture this traffic. Which would have been useful to have a high quality question.

Comment: Nothing happened to it.  The frame is 100 bytes long but the IP packet defines it's total length as 99 bytes.

Comment: David Hoelzer : Why does the IP packet defines it's total length as 99 bytes but not 100 bytes? I see this only for tls data transfer not dtls.

Comment: A capture file is always better for analysis than a screenshot, but my guess is that most likely there's an extraneous byte following the IP packet.

Answer (score 0):

100 bytes are bytes from 0 to 99 ! common mistake because index don't start at 1 but 0.

Comment: This is not the answer at all.  Have a look at the image:  "Frame 13: 100 bytes on wire", then look further down at the Internet Protocol's ip.len field, "Total length: 99".

Comment: It is saying length, not index. Moreover, I find this behaviour only with TCP data transfer not UDP.

Comment: Your right, I've not seen the image (thinking about programming) :(
Could someone remove my (wrong) answer? thanks!

Comment: By the way pavilion, you seems to be not on Ethernet (no Ethernet II layer) : as said Patrick Mevzek, we need some other details... on Ethernet, the IP layer will show size - 14 bytes (2x mac@ + 0x0800 ethertype)

Comment: Ok, ThreadX is an operating system (RT). A classical IP frame contains Ethernet addresses (source and destination) : why your screenshot don't have them ? how your OS is able to know the frame is for it ?
I know Ethernet but not this carrier protocol. I'm sorry but I'm unable to help you furthermore...